# What does the number 77 mean on the Schrader valve?

Tags: valves, schrader

[image: 77]

Can anyone please tell me what this number on the valve mean?

Comment: Could it be "LL"?

Comment: Probably "Inspected by inspector number 77."

Comment: Could it be "LL"? – Paul H 4 hours ago. I thought that too, as there is an LL printed in white on the tyre tube itself....I have tried to find what it means if it is 77 or if it is LL but I have been unable to find the meaning of either...if it is LL, do you know what that represents?

Comment: I've never seen a tube or valve with this.  Is it reflective?  Is it a particularly old tube from the days where some white paint was a "safety" thing?   Is there any other text written on the outside of the tube ?

Comment: It could be the length of the stem (in mm).  Measure it, and see if it comes close to that.

Comment: @PaulH Upside down 77 looks like: ㄥㄥ vs right side up: L L -- As you can see a 7 has a more acute angle than an L.

Comment: @Criggie Unfortunately the user posting this question is [unregistered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243712/post-as-guest-is-a-bad-user-experience-and-encourages-low-quality-contribution) so we may never find out.

Answer (score 3):

A Schrader valve has an external width of 7.7mm per the specification. The number written on your valve refers to this fact.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve#Dimensions

Comment: This is probably correct, but can you provide some proof that this is what the 77 refers to?

Comment: @AndyP  I've searched multiple times but can't find anything. Maybe a bike store employee could look through their collection of tubes and find another one with a white stripe and number on it?

Comment: I checked with the store guys once and he assumed its valve width

Comment: 7.7mm is the "OD" of the thread, the actual valve stem can be either 11.5mm or 16mm presuming we are just talking rubber stem Schrader Valves

Comment: For some reason I cant edit that comment above, but for the sake of being available, good old Sheldon Brown and a few other sites have the OD size listed as 7.7mm https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_sa-o.html